# Grep regular files in a linux File System and show their content

Tags: linux, grep, display

How do I display the content of files regular files matched with grep command? For example I grep a directory in order to see the regular files it has. I used the next line to see the regular files only:

```
ls -lR | grep ^-
```

Then I would like to display the content of the files found there. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. Would try to give you a few easy and clean ways here. All of them handle filenames with space.

**$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat**

-print0 adds a null character '\0' delimiter and you need to call xargs -0 to recognise the null delimiter. If you don't do that, whitespace in the filename create problems.

e.g. **without -print0** filenames: **abc 123.txt** and **1.inc** would be read as three separate files **abc**, **123.txt** and **1.inc**.

**with -print0** this becomes **abc 123.txt'\0'** and **1.inc'\0'** and would be read as **abc 123.txt** and **1.inc**

As for xargs, it can accept the input as a parameter. command1 | xargs command2 means the output of command1 is passed to command2.

cat displays the content of the file.

**$ find . -type f  -exec echo {} \; -exec cat {} \;**

This is just using the find command. It finds all the files (type f), calls echo to output the filename, then calls cat to display its content.

If you don't want the filename, omit -exec echo {} \;

Alternatively you can use cat command and pass the output of find.

**$ cat `find . -type f -print`**

If you want to scroll through the content of multiple files one by one. You can use.

**$ less `find . -type f -print`**

When using less, you can navigate through :n and :p for next and previous file respectively. press q to quit less.

Comment: Wow. The first one worked perfect. Now I need to figure out and study what you did there. Im really new at this. I appreciate a lot your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
$ cat `ls -lR | egrep "^-" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev`
```

- Use ls to find the files
- grep finds your pattern
- reverse the whole result
- cut out the first file separated field to get the file name (files with spaces are problematic)
- reverse the file name back to normal direction
- Backticks will execute that and return the list of file names to cat.

or the way I would probably do it is use vim to look at each file.

```
$ vim `ls -lR | egrep "^-" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev`
```

It feels like you are trying to find only the files recursively. This is what I do in those cases:

```
$ vim `find . -type f -print`
```

Comment: I was trying by parts, I am new at this. I could do that it returns me the names only, but i cannot display the file.
I used: 
´ls -lR | grep ^- | rev | cut -d " " -f 1 | rev´
I'll keep trying.

Comment: Comment has forward single ticks. Is it possible that you are not using back ticks? Back ticks are used to take the result of a command and make the results available as a variable in bash, which is what we want here so that cat or vim receives a list of files from the grep operation.

Comment: Im using the back ticks, in fact in linux i dont know why is the only one i can use haha. When i put the line, it says the file does not exists. I will keep on it. I really apreciate your help, I am learning a lot.